# Disable IntelliTrace during execution of application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, intellitrace

I have an application that loads a lot of metadata when starting up. This is done within a few seconds, but when I turn IntelliTrace on it takes ages. I understand why, but it makes it for me impossible to use IntelliTrace.

What I would like is to add a statement to my code to not record the IntelliTrace events and call information during this loading. After the load has finished, I want to add a statement that the IntelliTrace can record the information again.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Disable IT completely:

```
Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace -> [ ] Enable IntelliTrace
```

or figure out what exactly event type degrades the performance and disable it:

```
Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace -> IntelliTrace Events
```

Comment: It are not the events that are causing the degrade of the performance, but it is the call information. Based on your answer, can I conclude that is not possible to turn off Intellitrace temporary during the execution of the code?

Comment: @Ewald: I think you can write a macro which will do that for you, i.e. just turn on/off IT more quick then using Options dialog. In another words - you can just turn IT off, that's only way, afaik.

Comment: I am not trying to disable the Intellitrace before I start the debugging session. I want to temporary disable Intellitrace <b>while</b> I am in the debugging session.

Comment: any ***scripting cmd or powershell*** for put **ON** or **OFF** _IntelliTrace_ ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: I'm pretty sure you can change something in registry, don't know which key thought, try to search especially for it. Or use registry snapshots comparison software, i.e. before and after changing the settings.